# openapi-generator-maven-plugin (Java) does not handle allOf properly

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

With `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin`, I have noticed that using `allOf` composed of multiple objects in a response does not generate a class combining these multiple objects. Instead it uses the first class defined in the `allOf` section.

Here is a minimal example (`openapi.yaml`) :

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Test
  version: v1
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      operationId: get
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Get
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                allOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/A'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/B'
components:
  schemas:
    A:
      type: object
      properties:
        attA:
          type: string
    B:
      type: object
      properties:
        attB:
          type: integer
```

When generating the classes in Java via :

```
mvn org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:5.2.0:generate \
    -Dopenapi.generator.maven.plugin.inputSpec=openapi.yaml \
    -Dopenapi.generator.maven.plugin.generatorName=java
```

It shows a warning:

```
[WARNING] allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one: A
```

As expected, it generates classes A and B. But, when calling `get()`, the value returned by the call is of type `A`:

```java
DefaultApi api = new DefaultApi();
A a = api.get();
```

Instead, I would have expected a composite object containing `A` and `B` properties (`attA` and `attB`), like this (result from https://editor.swagger.io/):

[image: Result on swagger editor]

I have created [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/10010), but hopefully someone here may have had the same issue and managed to fix it.

Also, **I can't modify** the `openapi.yaml` file because it's an OpenAPI spec provided by an API I have to call, so modifying it would make no sense and will make it so difficult to manage if their OpenAPI spec change over time.

Comment: I'm afraid the generator will not create composite types itself. There would be multiple ways to do this anyway. It seems like an illusion that you won't have to change anything if that part of the api would change even if it would generate your composite class.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an issue tracker. You haven't asked a question, and you have simply pointed out a problem. We can't help you unless you ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 6.0.0 of `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` solves the issue by generating a class (`Get200Response`) composed of the two objects `A` and `B`. After generating the classes using:

```
mvn org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:6.0.0:generate \
    -Dopenapi.generator.maven.plugin.inputSpec=openapi.yaml \
    -Dopenapi.generator.maven.plugin.generatorName=java
```

I can see that new `Get200Response` class:

```java
package org.openapitools.client.model;

// ...

public class Get200Response {
  public static final String SERIALIZED_NAME_ATT_A = "attA";
  @SerializedName(SERIALIZED_NAME_ATT_A)
  private String attA;

  public static final String SERIALIZED_NAME_ATT_B = "attB";
  @SerializedName(SERIALIZED_NAME_ATT_B)
  private Integer attB;

  // ...
}
```

And I was able to make the following code work. In that example, I have a dummy webserver listening on port `5000` and defining a `/test` endpoint returning `{"attA": "hello", "attB": 1}`.

```java
package org.example;

import org.openapitools.client.ApiClient;
import org.openapitools.client.ApiException;
import org.openapitools.client.api.DefaultApi;
import org.openapitools.client.model.Get200Response;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ApiException {
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
    apiClient.setBasePath("http://localhost:5000");

    DefaultApi api = new DefaultApi(apiClient);
    Get200Response r = api.get();
    System.out.println(r.getAttA());
    System.out.println(r.getAttB());
  }
}
```

This successfully prints:

```
hello
1
```